# Nuget - Packages.Config utilizar últimas versões dos pacotes

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

**Cenário**

Tenho um projeto onde as minhas Libraries (outros componentes do projeto) são pacotes Nuget, e sempre que tem alguma atualização é gerado no Proget uma nova versão.. e todos os desenvolvedores tem que dar um update packages manualmente para que o TeamCity por exemplo utilize a última versão especificada no package.config.

Segue exemplo simplificado do meu arquivo **packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="BibliotecaX" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Gostaria de fazer de uma forma onde ao invés de especificar essa versão, utilizar o version por exemplo `version="2.0.*"` ou `version="2.*.*"` para quando o VisualStudio for fazer restore pegar sempre a última versão **(apenas de pacotes específicos)** onde eu faria essa configuração.

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão.

Comment: Qual a versão do nuget?

Comment: NuGet Version: 4.5.1.4879
Estou tentando contornar fazendo no PreBuild Events e chamando o comando dessa forma:
nuget update projeto.csproj -Id PacoteNuget

Comment: Tentou deixar o número de versão vazio?

Comment: **`<package id="BibliotecaX" version="" targetFramework="net461" />`**

Comment: Invalid package version for package id 'Newtonsoft.Json': '10.0.'
tentei com espaco tambem, ele ignora e nao funciona

Comment: Pelo que eu sei, isso que está tentando fazer não funciona, todo pacote tem que ter sua versão, é além das versões finais (release) tem as versões beta, ou seja, o arquivo tem que identificar o que precisa ... !!! Eu até pesquisei, por desencargo, porque crio pacotes não tem isso não ou não achei.

Comment: @LINQ nao deu certo , infelizmente

Comment: @VirgilioNovic o jeito vai ser fazer manualmente no prebuild com os comandos do nuget mesmo e atualizar, ta dando certo aqui estou testando, se eu conseguir finalizar com sucesso posto aqui a resposta detalhada. 
Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:
Converti o **packages.config** para **packagereferences**

Utilizei essa extension para me ajudar na migração:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CloudNimble.NuGetPackageReferenceUpgrader

Feito isso, dentro do CSProj fiz da seguinte forma: (o nome dos componentes são apenas exemplos)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" Version="4.2.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSubstitute" Version="3.1.*" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

Resolvido, no build ele baixa a última versão de acordo com a minha condição (1.0.*)